# Method usable in getting VS Code terminal to watch changes?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal

I have been trying to use `VS Code` built in terminal to watch and run upon any changes in my code.

I used `NodeJS` but it is not doing a perfect work because I have to call `node ...app.js` to make it run the code every time I needed to run it. Does anyone know an alternative to `NodeJS`?

I just want to make the IDE execute my code without me doing `console.log`, then switching to the browser.

Comment: Install [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) globally using `npm install -g nodemon`, and then use `nodemon app.js` to make it reload upon every change :) _(Ctrl + C to stop it)_

Comment: This has nothing to do with the vscode terminal. It doesn't watch changes, it cannot watch changes. It's just a terminal you can use to run other programs.

Comment: I tried nodemon, still didn't work.